Sufficient conditions for finiteness of first moment
Consider a random variable $X$ with full support such that
$$
(1)\quad E(\exp(\beta X))<\infty
$$
for some $\beta>0$. Could you help me to show that this implies
$$
(2)\quad E(|X|)<\infty
$$
I am not sure where to start from, and I lack any basic intuition as to why this is true.

You can start reasoning about the Taylor expansion of exp(b*x)

I don't think the implication statement in the question is true.  As a counterexample, just take a random variable that is sufficiently fat-tailed on the negative side (and a high value of $\beta$) that it has an infinite expected absolute value but not an infinite expected exponential value.

I agree with @Ben, further assumptions are needed.

Are you sure that $(1)$ doesn't have an $\vert X \vert$ instead of just an $X$?
